# how to download PDF from byteArray in angular 11?

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf, download, angular11

I have byte array  and  I want to download pdf without any library, for example  file-saver.

**service.ts**

```
    return this.http.get(`${this.invoiceUrl}/GenerateInvoice`,
         { responseType: "arraybuffer", observe: "response", params }
    );
```

**component.ts**

```
file(byte) {
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byte);
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');

    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type: 'application/json' }));
    a.download = "data.txt";

    // Append anchor to body.
    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click();


    // Remove anchor from body
    document.body.removeChild(a)
  }

//   download   function
    this.invoiceService.generateInvoice(id).pipe(
      finalize(() => this.loadingFlag = false)
    ).subscribe(
      resp => {
        console.log(resp);
         this.file(resp.body)
}
```

[image][image]

If I write this  version resp is :[image]

and  if  I rite:

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.invoiceUrl}/GenerateInvoice`,
  { responseType: "arraybuffer", observe: "response", params }
);
```

resp is
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: In the service file  there is no  need of responseType.

```
  downloadPDF(str) {
    const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + str;
    const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    const fileName = "sample.pdf";

    downloadLink.href = linkSource;
    downloadLink.download = fileName;
    downloadLink.click();
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this it's worked for me without file-saver:

```
file(data: any) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const pwa = window.open(url);
      if (!pwa || pwa.closed || typeof pwa.closed === 'undefined') {
        throw error( 'check if your browser block windows');
    }
 }
```

or you can use this example:

```
file(data: any) {
    const blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      let filename = 'myPdfFile';
      let url= URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = url;
      a.download = fileName;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

The first example open `pdf` on your **browser** and the second download the file.

Comment: There is  same error,  It  downloaded but it writes " failed to load pdf document

Comment: try to add this to your http request :
const httpOptionsPDF = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/pdf'
  })
};

{responseType: 'blob', headers: httpOptionsPDF.headers}

Comment: first you set the headers and update your http call params

Comment: I have updated  my question. If I write correctly what you say. It is same problem

Comment: OK, do u use chrome? witch function you implemente the first one or the second?

Comment: Yes, I use chrome.  Both of them, But  In this  example   second  one

Comment: i don't know why you receive type json !!

Comment: Midlware returns me :
 const response = await this.rest.request('controller/action', req.query, null, ap);

            res.json(response);

Comment: maybe you need to set it to byte return response